# Clojure how to mix/merge two maps

Tags: clojure, hashmap

I'm new in clojure and I need mix a very complex (for me) maps that have inside a Vector to mix up.

Orginal map:

```
{:cars   {:previous-page nil, :next-page 2, :count 33, :items [{:id 1, :name "test1"}, {:id 2, :name "test2"}]},
 :trucks {:previous-page nil, :next-page 2, :count 11, :items [{:id 1, :name "test3"}, {:id 2, :name "test4"}]},
 :boats  {:previous-page nil, :next-page 2, :count 22, :items [{:id 1, :name "test5"}, {:id 2, :name "test6"}]}}
```

Second map:

```
 {:cars   {:previous-page 2, :next-page 3, :count 33, :items [{:id 3, :name "test7"}, {:id 4, :name "test8"}]},
  :trucks {:previous-page 3, :next-page 4, :count 11, :items [{:id 3, :name "test9"}, {:id 4, :name "test10"}]},
  :boats  {:previous-page 4, :next-page 5, :count 22, :items [{:id 3, :name "test11"}, {:id 4, :name "test12"}]}}
```

I need to mix this two maps in only one:

```
{:cars   {:previous-page 2, :next-page 3, :count 33, :items [{:id 1, :name "test1"}, {:id 2, :name "test2"},{:id 3, :name "test7"}, {:id 4, :name "test8"}]},
 :trucks {:previous-page 3, :next-page 4, :count 11, :items [{:id 1, :name "test3"}, {:id 2, :name "test4"},{:id 3, :name "test9"}, {:id 4, :name "test10"}]},
 :boats  {:previous-page 4, :next-page 5, :count 22, :items [{:id 1, :name "test5"}, {:id 2, :name "test6"},{:id 3, :name "test11"}, {:id 4, :name "test12"}]}}
```

Comment: What is the rule for merging them?  Do you need a rule because you'll be routinely solving this problem or can you just fix up your data?

Comment: based on the result i would infer something like this: `(merge-with (partial merge-with #(if (coll? %1) (into %1 %2) %2))
                  map1 map2)`

Comment: @jmargolisvt I need replace the values of pagination (previous and next-page) and in the order hand I have to merge the items items: [{1},{2},{3},{4}]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `merge-with` to combine maps with an arbitrary function. Here there does not seem to be one "rule" though - for `:previous-page`,  `:next-page`, and `:count` seem to be "last one wins" but `:items seems to be something like`#(into [] %)`. Once you can state that rule clearly as a function:

```
(fn combine [map1 map2] ...)
```

You can then easily combine the maps with `merge-with` using whatever `combine` you've defined.